# Active Directory Root Forest Domain does not return referrals on querying on port 3268/3269

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

Active Directory forest root domain generally returns referral on querying directly but as soon as we provide a port 3268/3269 to the same domain, it provides results instead of referrals.
For eg. you can consider the following 2 queries with ldapsearch

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps://company-abcd.com -x -D "test\testuser" -W -b "DC=company-abcd,DC=com" "sAMAccountName=testuser" memberOf

ldapsearch -H ldaps://company-abcd.com:3269 -x -D "test\testuser" -W -b "DC=company-abcd,DC=com" "sAMAccountName=testuser" memberOf
```

What is the reason of above behaviour? Does querying on a port means we are querying one particular domain controller instead of a global catalog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't specify the port, the default port is used. The default port for LDAPS is 636. So your first request is connecting to port 636.

The LDAP or LDAPS ports (389 and 636) only return results for the domain of the server you are connecting to. So if the object you are asking for is on a different (but trusted) domain, then it is normal and expected that you will get a referral.

When you connect to port 3268 or 3269, you are asking for results from the global catalog, which will return results for every domain in the AD forest. So if the object you are looking for is on one of the domains in the forest, it will give you the result without a referral.

Comment: Got it, but what do you suggest in production for searching attribute say "memberOf" should we use with port that would mean a single global catalog or should we do SRV lookup search to check the list all available global catalogs or domain controllers before connecting?

Comment: When you connect using only the domain name (`company-abcd.com`), AD has a way to decide which server to send you to. So there is no benefit to doing an SRV lookup to figure it out yourself.

Comment: So do you mean if we put company-abcd.com:3269 would be the right thing to do for searching memberOf attribute for any user under any subdomains of company-abcd.com.

Comment: My only concern is if it is going to particular one global catalog and other global catalogs are missed out everytime even if we have say 100 Global Catalogs configured for our AD. Also if the particular GC is down, there is not any intelligent way of switching to another global catalog if we point out to one Gc and does not perform SRV lookup. Let me know your thoughts on this

Comment: Using a global catalog to look at `memberOf` is ok, as long as you're looking for groups where the Group Scope is Universal. I discussed this in an article I wrote: https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html#beware-of-memberof

Comment: Every time you do a DNS lookup on a domain name, it will give you a different DC. You can try this by running `nslookup company-abcd.com` in the command line over and over. So if one goes down, you just try again and it'll connect to a different one.